# RD selectmenu returns null if value different the label or option

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with a bit of Java code. The plugin is "RD selectmenu".

The error is simple...but I cannot seem to find the issue.

On a select input if the label (option) is not the same as the value it returns the word "null" onChange

I am not a java or query coder so I am putting it out to the community in hope to solve the error.

The code is dependant on Bootstrap V 3.3.6+ and JQuery.

```
(function() {
(function($, document, window) {

/**
 * Initial flags
 * @public
 */
var RDSelectMenu, isMobile;
isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

/**
 * Creates a select.
 * @class RDSelectMenu.
 * @public
 * @param {HTMLElement} element - The element to create the select for.
 * @param {Object} [options] - The options
 */
RDSelectMenu = (function() {

  /**
   * Default options for select.
   * @public
   */
  RDSelectMenu.prototype.Defaults = {
    valueIconClass: 'rd-select-value-icon fa-angle-down',
    callbacks: null
  };

  function RDSelectMenu(element, options) {
    this.options = $.extend(true, {}, this.Defaults, options);
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.$wrap = this.$element.wrap('<div class="rd-select"></div>').parent();
    this.$pseudoValue = null;
    this.$pseudoOptions = null;
    this.$win = $(window);
    this.$doc = $(document);
    this.initialize();
  }


  /**
   * Initializes the Parallax.
   * @protected
   */

  RDSelectMenu.prototype.initialize = function() {
    var ctx;
    ctx = this;
    ctx.hideOriginalDOM();
    ctx.createPseudoDOM();
    ctx.applyHandlers();
    return ctx;
  };


  /**
   * Appends select pseudo DOM
   * @protected
   */

  RDSelectMenu.prototype.createPseudoDOM = function() {
    var ctx;
    ctx = this;
    ctx.$pseudoValue = $('<div/>', {
      'class': 'rd-select-trigger ' + ctx.$element.get(0).className
    }).append('<span class="rd-select-value">' + ctx.$element.find('option:selected').text() + '</span>').append('<span class="' + ctx.options.valueIconClass + '"></span>');
    ctx.$pseudoOptions = $('<ul/>', {
      'class': 'rd-select-menu'
    });
    ctx.$element.find('option').each(function() {
      var $option;
      $option = $(this);
      return ctx.$pseudoOptions.append($('<li/>', {
        'class': 'rd-select-option',
        'text': $option.text()
      }).addClass($option.is(':selected') ? 'selected' : false));
    });
    ctx.$wrap.append(ctx.$pseudoValue).append(ctx.$pseudoOptions);
    return ctx;
  };


  /**
   * Hides original select
   * @protected
   */

  RDSelectMenu.prototype.hideOriginalDOM = function() {
    var ctx;
    ctx = this;
    ctx.$element.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      margin: 0,
      padding: 0,
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: isMobile ? '100%' : 0,
      height: isMobile ? '100%' : 0,
      border: 'none',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      opacity: 0,
      'z-index': isMobile ? 9999999 : -9999999
    });
    return ctx;
  };


  /**
   * Open select menu
   * @protected
   */

  RDSelectMenu.prototype.open = function() {
    var ctx;
    ctx = this;
    ctx.$wrap.addClass('rd-select-open');
    if (!ctx.$element.is(':focus')) {
      ctx.$element.focus();
    }
    return ctx;
  };


  /**
   * Close select menu
   * @protected
   */

  RDSelectMenu.prototype.close = function() {
    var ctx;
    ctx = this;
    ctx.$wrap.removeClass('rd-select-open');
    return ctx;
  };

  RDSelectMenu.prototype.change = function(ctx, e) {
    var $this;
    $this = $(this);
    ctx.$element.val($this.text()).trigger('change').trigger('propertychange').focus();
    if (e.type === 'click') {
      $.proxy(ctx.close, ctx)();
    }
    return this;
  };

  RDSelectMenu.prototype.originalChange = function() {
    this.$pseudoValue.find('.rd-select-value').text(this.$element.val());
    this.$pseudoOptions.find('.rd-select-option').eq(this.$element.find('option:selected').index()).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    return this;
  };

  RDSelectMenu.prototype.keyDown = function(e) {
    var next, prev;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 32:
      case 37:
      case 39:
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
      case 38:
        e.preventDefault();
        prev = this.$pseudoOptions.find('.rd-select-option.selected').prev();
        if (prev.length) {
          $.proxy(this.change, prev[0], this)(e);
        }
        break;
      case 40:
        e.preventDefault();
        next = this.$pseudoOptions.find('.rd-select-option.selected').next();
        if (next.length) {
          $.proxy(this.change, next[0], this)(e);
        }
        break;
      case 13:
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.$wrap.hasClass('rd-select-open')) {
          $.proxy(this.close, this)();
        } else {
          $.proxy(this.open, this)();
        }
    }
  };


  /**
   * Apply all select event handlers
   * @protected
   */

  RDSelectMenu.prototype.applyHandlers = function() {
    var ctx;
    ctx = this;
    if (!isMobile) {
      ctx.$element.on('focus', $.proxy(ctx.open, ctx));
      ctx.$doc.find('*').on('focus', function(e) {
        var target;
        target = e.target;
        if (target !== ctx.$element[0] && !$(target).parents('.rd-select-menu').length) {
          return $.proxy(ctx.close, ctx)();
        }
      });
      ctx.$element.on('keydown', $.proxy(ctx.keyDown, ctx));
      ctx.$pseudoValue.on('click', $.proxy(ctx.open, ctx));
      ctx.$pseudoOptions.find('li').each(function() {
        var $this;
        $this = $(this);
        return $this.on('click', $.proxy(ctx.change, this, ctx));
      });
      ctx.$doc.on('click', function(e) {
        var target;
        target = e.target;
        if (target !== ctx.$wrap[0] && !$(target).parents('.rd-select').length) {
          return $.proxy(ctx.close, ctx)();
        }
      });
    }
    ctx.$element.on('change propertychange', $.proxy(ctx.originalChange, ctx));
    return ctx;
  };

  return RDSelectMenu;

})();

/**
 * The jQuery Plugin for the RD Parallax
 * @public
 */
$.fn.extend({
  RDSelectMenu: function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this;
      $this = $(this);
      if (!$this.data('RDSelectMenu')) {
        return $this.data('RDSelectMenu', new RDSelectMenu(this, options));
      }
    });
  }
});
return window.RDSelectMenu = RDSelectMenu;
})(window.jQuery, document, window);


   /**
 * The Plugin AMD export
 * @public
 */

  if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module !== null) {
module.exports = window.RDSelectMenu;
 } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
define(["jquery"], function() {
  'use strict';
  return window.RDSelectMenu;
});
}

}).call(this);

   HTML Code

    <div class="form-group">
                <select id="pick" name="pick" class="rd-mailform-select form-control">
                      <option value="">Select Asset Type...</option>
                      <option value="1" >Property</option>
                      <option value="2">Vehicle</option>
                      <option value="3">Boat</option>
                      <option value="4">Luxury Item</option>
                    </select>

        </div>
```